# Laravel exception handling without try/catch statement

Tags: php, laravel, exception

I'm wondering is a good practice to throw exceptions without try/catch statement. For example

/// Class Driver

```
class Driver{

 public function setAge($age)
   if(is_string($age)){
      throw new StringException('Age can not be string')
   }
   if($age>100){
      throw new TooLargeNumberException('Age is too large')
   }
}
```

///Controller

```
$d= new Driver()
$d->setAge(101) /// return TooLargeNumberException
```

Or

```
try{
$d= new Driver()
$d->setAge(101)
}
catch(StringException $e){
 return $e->getMessage()
}
catch(TooLargeNumberException $e){
return $e->getMessage()
}
```

Please advice me how to handle with exceptions. Which solution is correct? Is it neccesarily to use always try/catch statement?

Comment: Is your question whether you should throw exceptions at your users or how to best handle exceptions across your application?

Comment: IMO, you're handling the whole process wrong. Set the age just by doing `$driver->age = 50;` (or better yet, store a birthday instead). Handle the limitations via validation on the requests that modify the age.

Comment: Use form validation https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#validation-quickstart so you can gracefully return errors to the user about what they need to fix.

Comment: I would like to know how to best handle exceptions across  application. Please don't care the content of example .My code is just simple example of throwing execptions. I know that laravel has exception handler which helps to create error views. I' learnig laravel but my question is general to PHP. Is it  s it neccesarily to use always try/catch statement? Is it bad practice to use only throw statement as in first example? I can't see the difference between these two examples. Result is the same. That is the rerason of my question. What is the benefit of try/catch statement?

Answer (score 2):

Laravel has a general exception handler where all uncaught exceptions go to:

`App\Exceptions\Handler`

There are two methods in this class:  `report` and `render` with which you can take the necessary actions.

Please see:  https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/errors

That is to say, you can `throw` the exceptions inside `class Driver`, and not need to handle them specifically in the controller, you can have a general exception handling strategy defined in your `Handler` class.